# I have a tacklife 10 in table saw and switch burnt out. Can I buy any table saw switch or does it have to be specific

Tags: woodworking

Tacklife 10in table saw
Burnt out switch
What switch can I buy to replace

Comment: For a simple on/off switch, can usually use any switch of the same voltage and amps work, might not look as nice and might need to change mounting.  Should replace with same type, locking or non locking, but the volts and amps are the main things to check for.

Comment: As phrased, this is kind of a shopping question, which is off limits. But... I'd suggest you contact the manufacturer. Some on/off switches are smart (ie, my Bosch tablesaw), and some are really basic. You need to figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the old switch and screw a surface mount switch box over the opening. Feed the old wires into the box and install a 20-amp rated double-pole switch (Hubbel, etc) If you like, you can paint the switch lever red.